# how to : define and get a custom report from google analytics using gapi

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have  a custom report called my-newsletters in Google analytics.  I want to fetch this report with a php call to `$ga->requestReportData(...)` and then parse the response and format it up.

First I made an account to collect all my newsletter open and click hits  - each time someone opens a newsletter or clicks on a link in the newsletter I capture that with a call to the __utm.gif on Google.  That part is working and I include in the call ( in the Landing Page aka utmp parameter) some data such as the word 'open' and 'click' to distinguish the events and  also some other data i hope to parse out later, plus i use the campaign field and maybe I should do something with the source field too - now I just dup the utmp field.  So far that part seems to work.

Now I need help to define a report that will return that utmp and  campaign field info and the number of hits each has taken, sorted by date of hit I guess. then i need to call that report from my php and then later parse it - the parsing part I'm not worried about yet.

PS: here is the code I use to generate the utm url

```
function getGoogleUtmUrl($source='Emails', $referer='opens', $estid='0',$mailid='0', $campaign){
  $stat_id='MO-xxx31982-1';
    $var_utmcs=urlencode( 'UTF-8');
    $var_utmac = $stat_id; 
    $var_utmhn = 'mysite.com'; //enter your domain
    $var_utmn = rand(1000000000,9999999999); //random request number
    $var_cookie = rand(10000000,99999999); //random cookie number
    $var_random = rand(1000000000,2147483647); //number under 2147483647
    $var_today = time(); //today
    $var_referer = $referer; //referer url
    $utm_source = 'my_newsletter';
    $utm_medium = 'Emails';
    $utm_campaign = $campaign;//$_GET['url'];
    $var_uservar = $estid.'_'.$mailid; //enter your own user defined variable
    $var_utmp = 'mysite.com/newsletters/'.$referer.'/'.$estid.'/'.$mailid;//.$estid;//$_GET['url']; //this example adds a fake file request to the (fake) tracker directory (the image/pdf filename).
    $urchinUrl1 = 'http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif?utmwv=4.3&utmn='.$var_utmn.'&utmsr='.$referer.'&utmcs='.$var_utmcs.
        '&utmul=en&utmje=0&utmfl=-&utmdt='.$utm_campaign.'&utmhn='.$var_utmhn.
        '&utm_source='.$var_utmp.'&utm_medium='.$utm_medium.'&utm_campaign='.$utm_campaign.'&utmr='.$var_referer.
        '&utmp='.$var_utmp.'&utmac='.$var_utmac.
        '&utmcc=__utma%3D'.$var_cookie.'.'.$var_random.'.'.
        $var_today.'.'.$var_today.'.'.$var_today.
        '.2%3B%2B__utmb%3D'.$var_cookie.'%3B%2B__utmc%3D'.
        $var_cookie.'%3B%2B__utmz%3D'.$var_cookie.'.'.$var_today.
        '.2.2.utmccn%3D(direct)%7Cutmcsr%3D(direct)%7Cutmcmd%3D(none)%3B%2B__utmv%3D'.
        $var_cookie.'.'.'%3B';
    // Now fire off the HTTP request
    echo "urchinURL1 == ".$urchinUrl1.' '.__FILE__.'  '.__LINE__.'<br/>';
    return $urchinUrl1;
```

seems like over kill to me but it works, I tried the code at https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/other/mobileWebsites and it doesn't work - the opens and clicks do not register in analytics - at least not on the real time page.

Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest that you build your report query first, I recommend that you use [Google Analytics Query Explorer](http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/) for that.

And next use the [reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/) from [PHP](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/gdataLibraries) to transpose the resulting query and extract the data from within your app.

Comment: thanks, i had not found that explorer tool before, it helped.